# IF there is another row

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to write an if statement to check if their is another row after the current one in the database. Where the current one is the `id` of the page.

```
<?php if($new_id>id): ?>
yes
<?php else: ?>
no
<?php endif; ?>
```

`$new_id` is the selected page. so if their is an entry after it it will say yes, or if it the most recent addition it will say no.

I know how to do this in a select statement: `WHERE id>$new_id`
this tells me if there is another row after it but I don't know how to write it as an IF statement.

Comment: OFF: Not `their is` but `there is`. :)

Comment: would help to know which DB system and driver you are using... without it - impossible to tell

Comment: `select id from yourtable where id>$nw_id` and `if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { there's more ids }`

Comment: It also depends what you mean by "after". If you have some unique ID, you could retrieve the latest one (`SELECT MAX(id) FROM ...`) and compare to that. If you are retrieving _all_ the rows, you could check if you are in the last record of your result set, details depending on the driver you are using.

Comment: Maybe better: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE id > $nEw_id LIMIT 1`

Comment: @biziclop: why the limit? select count(*) would return one row only anyways.

Comment: By 'after' I mean is it the latest addition to the database. If there is nothing after it then it is.
@Marc B, I know how to do the `select` statement for getting the variables. I'm already using it. Now I'm essentially trying to hide the variables if there are no more records in the database and show them if THERE are.

Comment: @MarcB: I was actually thinking something like this: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( SELECT 1 FROM yourtable WHERE id > $new_id LIMIT 1 ) AS t` or this: `SELECT EXIST ( SELECT 1 FROM yourtable WHERE id > $new_id LIMIT 1 )` :)

Comment: either way, those'd return a row of data, and you' have to fetch the row to see what's in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a `post` table with an autoincrementing `id` field using MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE post (
   id       INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   ...
   PRIMARY KEY ( id )
);
```

You could use something like this (pseudo-php):

```
<?php
  // somehow you calculate the current id
  $the_id = your_get_the_id_func();

  // then execute this sql row with your favourite sql library
  // and get the returned single value which may be the stings '0' or '1'
  $has_newer_post = your_exec_sql_and_get_sql_value("
    SELECT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM post WHERE id > $the_id LIMIT 1 );
  ");
?>

<?php
  // if('0') === if(false) only in php: http://codepad.org/IlUx8J1Y
  if( $has_newer_post ) :
?>
  yes
<?php else: ?>
  no
<?php endif; ?>
```